Dexie.js: observe only one field
Is there a way to observe only a single field in a Dexie.js liveQuery, so that it does not get re-rendered every time an unrelated field is modified in the same object? Ideally, I'd like to observe a nested field, like in:
mytable.put({
  name: "foo",
  properties: {propA: 42, propB: 52}
})

How can I react to changes on propA only? Also, is it possible to do the same with arrays, like in:
mytable.put({
  name: "foo",
  properties: [["propA", 42] ["propB", 52]]
})

I'm asking since the first option cannot be indexed by indexedbd (the name of the prop is not know when creating the database so I can't use keypath) so I might need to represent data using the second notation.
